# How to create a zip file on SFTP server from files on the server using pysftp

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, sftp, pysftp

I want to write a Python script that connects to the remote SFTP server and creates a ZIP file in the remote server which consists of specific files present in remote server itself. I have written the below script, I m using pysftp for this,

```
with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
    files = ['user/1.csv','user/2.csv','user/test.csv', 'user/test1.csv']
    with zipfile.ZipFile('zipfile.zip', 'w') as zipMe:
        for file in files:
            zipMe.write(file, file.split('/')[-1], compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

But instead of creating a ZIP file in the remote server, an ZIP file gets created in the local. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you code compresses *local* files to *local* ZIP archive. Note how your code never uses the `sftp` variable.

If you want to compress *remote* files to *remote* ZIP archive using a *local* Python script, you have to download the remote files, zip them locally and upload the ZIP archive.

You can do that all that "in-memory" without actually storing the remote files or the ZIP file physically to the local system. But you still need to do all the transfers. So it will be terribly inefficient.

---

You better execute `zip` command on the remote server using your SFTP (or SSH actually) connection.

Related question: [How to decode Zip file from sftp file using paramiko python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58802771/850848)